# How to web scrape IMDB movie rating

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the the movie rating from IMDB website.
However I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

when using this code:

```
rating_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596343/?ref_=tt_urv')
 
rating_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(rating_sauce, 'html.parser')
 
#container = rating_soup.find('div', {'class':'ipc-button__text'})
 
rating = rating_soup.find('span', {'class':'AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-11129m0-1'}).text

print("Movie Rating::" + rating)
```

Comment: Typo.  You are looking for `sc-11129m0-1` when it should be `sc-1ll29m0-1`.  That is, "ess cee dash one ell ell two nine".

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

It still giving me this error.

Comment: Use this - ```rating_soup.find('span', {'class':'AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1'}).text```

Comment: @Ram I tried but same issue I am facing

Answer (score 1):

You need to try changing the value of *rating = rating_soup.find('span', {'class':'**AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-11129m0-1**'})*.text               by inspecting what is the current value against that specific element.

Here is my working code

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

rating_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596343/?ref_=tt_urv')
rating_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(rating_sauce, 'html.parser')
 
 
rating = rating_soup.find('span', {'class':'sc-7ab21ed2-1 jGRxWM'}).text

print("Movie Rating::" + rating)
```

with this **output**

```
Movie Rating::7.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it's not working for you.
Try this

```py
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

rating_sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1596343/?ref_=tt_urv')
rating_soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(rating_sauce, 'html.parser')
 
 
rating = rating_soup.find('span', {'class':'AggregateRatingButton__RatingScore-sc-1ll29m0-1'}).text

print("Movie Rating::" + rating)
```

```
Movie Rating::7.3
```

Comment: Yeah. I really cant figure out what could be the problem as my code is working fine on Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Well,. then, what's NOT working?  Are you trying this behind a corporate firewall that blocks IMDB?

Comment: If firewall is the problem then it shouldn't be working on Jupyter Notebook but it isn't the case here.